# Java URL class sometimes dropping paths of path for 'file' protocol

Tags: java, url, constructor

Given the following code:

```
class testurl
{
    public void test()
    {
        try {
            URL url1 = new URL("file:../../foo/bar/");
            URL url2 = new URL(url1, "file.txt");

            URL url3 = new URL("file:../../../../foo/bar/");
            URL url4 = new URL(url3, "file.txt");

            URL url5 = new URL("file:../../../../../foo/bar/");
            URL url6 = new URL(url5, "file.txt");

            System.out.println("url1: " + url1.toString());
            System.out.println("url2: " + url2.toString());
            System.out.println("url3: " + url3.toString());
            System.out.println("url4: " + url4.toString());
            System.out.println("url5: " + url5.toString());
            System.out.println("url6: " + url6.toString());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            System.out.println("MalformedURLException Exception:");
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testurl obj = new testurl();
        obj.test();
    }
}
```

I see the following output:

```
url1: file:../../foo/bar/
url2: file:../../foo/bar/file.txt
url3: file:../../../../foo/bar/
url4: file:../../foo/bar/file.txt
url5: file:../../../../../foo/bar/
url6: file:../foo/bar/file.txt
```

It looks like the URL class is dropping parts of the path anytime I have move morethan two (2) '../' relative directories in the path of an URL object using the 'file' protocol, when I use the

```
URL(URL, String)
```

constructor, parts of the path get removed during construction.  I tried using a *'//'* after the *file:* in the URL, but it doesn't make any difference.

Am I doing something wrong? or is this just working as designed?
If so, is it possible to append/replace a the file portion of a URL
without deconstructing it first using the *getPath* or *getFile*
methods of the URL object?

Isn't that what the constructor I'm using is designed to do?

I've checked the Java trail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html
and it says:

```
You can create URL objects for these pages relative to their common base
URL:http://example.com/pages/ like this:

URL myURL = new URL("http://example.com/pages/");
URL page1URL = new URL(myURL, "page1.html");
URL page2URL = new URL(myURL, "page2.html");
```

So it appears I'm using it as expected.

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to try and create a URL from another relative URL. You have to do it from a absolute path URL. I'm not sure why it behaves as it does though...(does the same for me as for you).